# Need help on formating a line using sed

Tags: linux, sed, grep

The following is the line that I wanted to split it to tab separate part.

```
>VFG000676(gb|AAD32411)_(lef)_anthrax_toxin_lethal_factor_precursor_[Anthrax_toxin_(VF0142)]_[Bacillus_anthracis_str._Sterne]
```

the output that I want is

```
>VFG000676\t(gb|AAD32411)\t(lef)\tanthrax_toxin_lethal_factor_precursor\t [Anthrax_toxin_(VF0142)]\t[Bacillus_anthracis_str._Sterne]
```

I used this command

```
grep '>' x.fa | sed 's/^>\(.*\) (gi.*) \(.*\) \[\(.*\)\].*/\1\t\2\t\3/' | sed 's/ /_/g' > output.tsv
```

but the output is not what I want.

UPDATE: I finally fixed the issue by using the following code

```
grep '>' VFs_no_block.fa | sed 's/^>\(.*\)\((.*)\) \((.*)\) \(.*\) \(\[.*(.*)]\) \(\[.*]\).*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6/' | sed 's/ /_/g' > VFDB_annotation_reference.tsv
```

Comment: please add a short description as title (which contains more information than just the [tag]s)

Comment: and can you (also) describe (in words) how you want to split the input string?

Answer (score 1):

Change `OFS="\\t"` to `OFS="\t"` if you really wanted literal tabs:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\\t" }
{
    c=0
    while ( match($0,/\[[^][]+\]|\([^)(]+\)|[^][)(]+/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/^_+|_+$/,"",tgt)
        if (tgt != "") {
            printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), tgt
        }
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
>VFG000676\t(gb|AAD32411)\t(lef)\tanthrax_toxin_lethal_factor_precursor\t[Anthrax_toxin_(VF0142)]\t[Bacillus_anthracis_str._Sterne]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.